# Running a MongoDB Query over and over using C# and getting slower

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm hoping someone can give me some insight into this oddity.  I don't know if there's a leak of some kind or my way of using MongoDB is wacky wrong.  I copied some code from the [MongoDB CSharp ecosystem tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-csharp-driver/).  As I started messing with it, I noticed the time to perform a query was gradually rising.  I'm using C# 4.5, MongoDB 2.4.5, and running Windows 7.

The time to perform the initial query took approx 33 ms, but with each iteration of the loop it gradually increases.  Each time I run this code, the query time starts at approx 33 ms but increases to 61 ms.  If I use the ID it starts at 15 ms and increases to 34 ms.  I also tried using both Linq and the native EQ style syntax with the Query object and had similar increasing results.  I would have expected the time to increase and decrease with each iteration, but not constantly increase.  I'm pretty new to MongoDB, the first time I saw it was 2 days ago so any insight to finding out what is happening or what's wrong with the way I'm using the code would be appreciated.  (*Why did I do this -- I happened to notice off chance that the same query was getting slower and got curious*)

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;

namespace Snippets
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase("test");

            var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

            var entity = new Entity { Name = "X" };

            collection.Insert(entity);

            var query = Query<Entity>.Where(e => e.Name == "X");

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                sw.Start();

                var item = collection.FindOne(query);

                sw.Stop();

                Console.WriteLine("{0:0} ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }

            collection.Remove(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, how does it behave when you perform 1,000 or 5,000 queries? Are times still increasing? Maybe this is related to connection pooling. Also, you might want to eliminate potential profiling problems as discussed in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61964/Performance-Tests-Precise-Run-Time-Measurements-wi

Comment: Interesting! ... at 1,000 iterations it took almost two seconds which coincidentally was about the same time as the program run.  So I moved this line "Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();" inside the for loop and it solved the issue.  So MongoDB works just fine, and it was my ignorance with the Stopwatch usage by not calling "Reset".  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I was incorrectly using the Stopwatch by not calling Reset() prior to Start().  So this actually had nothing to do with MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it will be getting slower, because you need to index on the collection on `Name` since you do the query `collection.FindOne(query);` filtering on `Name` field.